# Weird : Why Powershell refuses to start-transcript if path not hard-coded

Tags: powershell

I have something like this :

```
$transcript_file=("$log_directory" + "Console_Log_" + $product_name  + ".txt")
start-transcript -path $stranscript_file
```

I check path var is correct. But I get exception when using that var. I have no exception if I put content of var. Why ?

Comment: Please show the text of the exception.

Comment: The exception will probably say "Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Path'. The argument is null or empty.". What it probably *should* say is "WTH is 'stranscript_file'?". :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo, that message is pretty clear: "The argument is null or empty. Supply an argument that is not null or empty and then try the command again." The lesson here (for user310291) is to actually read error messages. They can be very helpful.

Comment: @paxdiablo, if you put this at the top of the script `Set-StrictMode -Version Latest`, then you will get something similar to your "WTH" message: "The variable '$stranscript_file' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing you should do is print out the value you're passing to `start-transcript`.

If you do that *accurately,* you'll probably find out that it's empty because, hyper-intelligent machines notwithstanding, computers won't be able to tell that you intended `transcript_file` and `stranscript_file` to be the same thing:

```
PS C:\Pax> $transcript_file=("$log_directory" + "Console_Log_" + $product_name  + ".txt")

PS C:\Pax> $stranscript_file


PS C:\Pax> $transcript_file
Console_Log_.txt
```

Correct the variable name that you're passing as the path to `start-transcript` and all should be well (or at least until you strike the *next* issue).

---

As pointed out in a comment, it's a good idea (meaning I will be doing this from now on as well) to put:

```
set-strictmode -version latest
```

at the tops of your scripts, *at least* during development. One of the things that picks up is use of variables which haven't yet been set, which would have provided a (hopefully) more obvious error message.